# How to call the next element (that may change) from a certain element (that does not)

Tags: jquery

I have a modal that pops up when you click in a textbox. When you hit accept on the modal it does not focus into the next element that follows. The focus appears to jump off the page back up to the title tab.

What is making this difficult is that I cannot just have accept focus on one specific element by calling its id because the next element is not always the same it changes based on another dropdown. So I am trying to figure out if there is a way to call the next element after my (#purchaseprice) -- ID (textbox). Is there a way to call the next element no matter what it is after an element?

What I was trying was to do an if statement and list all the ones it could be, but that doesn't seem to be doing what I am trying. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(".dealer_accept").click(function(){
    $('#modal_special_outofstate').modal('hide');
    if ($('#ostatus').length > 0) {
        $("#ostatus").focus();
    } else if ($('#lien').length > 0) {
        $("#lien").focus();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just use the jQuery `.next()` function!  It accepts the usual selector strings, as well!

If you provided the HTML I could write actual code for this, but I would just make whatever is the next item that you want focused always share the same class.

So, something like:

```
$(".dealer_accept").click(function(){
    $('#modal_special_outofstate').modal('hide');

    //is the next element the next element after what you're clicking?
    $(this).next(".nextElementClass").focus();
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: Where does `#purchaseprice` come from?  Please provide HTML so I can see what we're working with.

Comment: Yes, then use $("#purchaseprice").next(".someClass") or if you're absolutely sure the next element is going to be, say, a div you can use `.next("div")`, etc.  Use a selector inside of `next()` just like any other jQuery selector.

Comment: Add a class to each of the potential elements and use that class as the selector.

Comment: Again, I have no idea what your HTML looks like, but the .next() function will work for you.  I just gave you an example of how to use it.  Post some HTML!!

Comment: It would be `.next("input")`, the word `input` with no quotes is a variable (undefined).

Comment: Can you not add a class to each of the potential next elements?

Comment: I edited my question can u look at the code? Even when #ostatus is not visible it still says it exists and never skips to the next if statement. Is there an if I can write for is visible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90636/discussion-between-vicki-and-seankendle).